vue-tiny-validate not validates and no rules got executed
I have a vuejs application and where I can dynamically add rows with some input fields (langugeId, type and name). Those are required fields. I am using vue-tiny-validate for validation library.
My idea is that every time I add/remove a line I regenerate the number of rules.
When I click the save button the function got called, the $test() function executes, but the $invalid valid property is always false. Putting breakpoint in every rule test function, the code never hit them (it should!).
  const createAttachmentRules = (attachments) => {
    const rules = {};
    attachments?.forEach((attachment, index) => {
      rules[index] = {
        type: {
          name: 'required',
          test: value => Number(value) >= 0,
          message: props.translation('Validation.Required')
        },
        languageId: {
          name: 'required',
          test: value => Number(value) >= 0,
          message: props.translation('Validation.Required')
        },
        name: {
          name: 'required',
          test: value => !!value,
          message: props.translation('Validation.Required')
        }
      };
    });

    return reactive(rules);
  };
 
  const attachmentRules = createAttachmentRules();
  const { result } = useValidate(state.attachments, attachmentRules, validationOptions);

 watch(() => state.attachments, (updatedAttachment) => {
    Object.assign(result, createAttachmentRules(updatedAttachment));
  });

const onSaveAsync = async (moveToNextTab = false) => {
    await result.value.$test();
    if (result.value.$invalid) {
      return;
    }   
  }


A property named invalid being false indicates something is valid - ?
